# Facebook IFrame App Question (Flash, PHP, MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, flash, facebook

I am developing a Flash game for Facebook that uses PHP to access MySQL to store users game info. I am a bit stuck right now though. Here is my scenario.

1. User logs into Facebook and starts app which calls index.php and houses my Flash game. (works fine).
2. I use $facebook->getUser(); to authenticate and begin gathering user information (also works fine).
3. Flash will then access a getdata.php file on my server that will access MySql and echo certain info (ie. fname=John&lname=Doe&age=25).

Step 3 is the problem and I'll do my best to explain it...

My getdata.php also does a $facebook->getUser(); authentication, but the user is NOT authenticated on that script, whereas within the IFRAME app, the user is still authenticated. I'm assuming it has something to do with the fact that the main page is within Facebook's IFRAME and is possibly seen as a different session than when Flash tries to connect with my getdata.php file on my server. Is this the case? And can anyone help point me in the right direction as to how I might use Flash within an IFrame app to access a script on my server to retreive variables?

EDIT: I should mention that I'm using ActionScript 3 for Flash, but I'm fairly certain the problem doesn't lie there because it will retrieve the variables, but since the user is not authenticated on the server, then it will return a success=0.

Also wanted to point out that if I access my flash game through my actual server, and not Facebook, then all works well. Another reason why I think it's a session-type problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a session problem. You should try to pass the facebook `signed_request`, or any data you can use to build a valid user session, into your flash file and then pass them back to getdata.php where it can be used to access the users data.